# Cannot run static enhancement of OpenJPA entities with Spring Boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin

`mvn package` fails at the [`openjpa-maven-plugin:enhance`](http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-maven.html) stage when I try to enhance my JPA entities in a Spring Boot app.

There's a long error description

`enhance failed: MetaDataFactory could not be configured (conf.newMetaDataFactoryInstance() returned null).`

`no configuration properties were found.`

It lists some reasons:

1. > Ensure that you have a META-INF/persistence.xml file, that it is
   >   available in your classpath

   - I'm using `spring-data-jpa` with Java config, and there's no
     `persistence.xml`. **Is it possible to do `openjpa:enhance` without

     it?**
2. > Ensure the properties file you are using for configuration is
   >   available. If you are using Ant, please see the  or
   >    attributes of the task's nested  element.

   - I specify all the OpenJPA properties in a subclass of Spring's [`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration.html) - see the class below. **This is probably what I need to change, but how? And where to specify the properties file so `openjpa-maven-plugin` can find it?**
3. > This can also occur if your OpenJPA distribution jars are corrupt, or
   >   if your security policy is overly strict.

   - ruled out - I checked redownloaded the OpenJPA jars with `checksumPolicy=fail` so that's proof that they're not corrupted, plus I'm not using any security policy at this level.

**pom.xml**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/entity/*.class</includes>
                <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enhancer</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**openjpa-maven-plugin error**

```
[INFO] --- openjpa-maven-plugin:2.4.1:enhance (enhancer) @ project-x ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.707 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-15T09:51:36+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/359M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-maven-plugin:2.4.1:enhance 
(enhancer) on project x: Execution enhancer of goal org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-maven-plugin:2.4.1:enhance 
failed: MetaDataFactory could not be configured (conf.newMetaDataFactoryInstance()
returned null). This might mean that no configuration properties were found. Ensure that 
you have a META-INF/persistence.xml file, that it is available in your classpath, or that
the properties file you are using for configuration is available. If you are using Ant,
please see the <properties> or <propertiesFile> attributes of the task's nested <config>
element. This can also occur if your OpenJPA distribution jars are corrupt, or if your
security policy is overly strict. -> [Help 1]
```

**Subclass of `JpaBaseConfiguration`**

```
@Import({
        LdapConfig.class,
        SecurityConfig.class,
        PropertySpringConfig.class
})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.adam.x.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.adam.x.entity"})
public class MyWebApplication extends JpaBaseConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    protected MyWebApplication(
            DataSource dataSource,
            JpaProperties properties,
            ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManagerProvider) {
        super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManagerProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        OpenJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new OpenJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return jpaVendorAdapter;

    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("openjpa.Log", "DefaultLevel=TRACE, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE, Runtime=TRACE");
        map.put("openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults", "IndexLogicalForeignKeys=false,IndexDiscriminator=false");
//        map.put("openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings", "buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)");
        map.put("openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses", "supported");
//        map.put("openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent", "true");
//        map.put("openjpa.weaving", "false");
        return map;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer here sorted it out for me.

The maven plugin needs a `persistence.xml` to work, which is slightly not DRY because I have to remember to list any new entity beans in there, but I figured it's a small price.

[OpenJPA and Spring-boot configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140463/openjpa-and-spring-boot-configuration?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-43625869)

Comment: Facing same issue can you please elaborate more to this answer?

Comment: have you created a `persistence.xml`? That is the solution, even though it's not necessary for anything except the maven openjpa plugin. But this was 3 years ago. Have you checked for new releases of the packages?